enable ssh service by editing files directly
I was making a raid1 filesystem using sgdisk, mdadm, update-initramfs and got, after reboot, locked out of remote machine running a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04. ssh times out, so I assume ssh did not start after reboot.
I am in the rescue mode and am looking at the service files. My guess is that sshd is not enabled. I tried chrooting and executing systemctl enable ssh, but systemctl does now work when chrooted.
I'd like to manually update sshd service files, so that they reflect enabled state.
This is the contents of /os/etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.requires/ssh.socket where /os is  where original OS fs is mounted:
`[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server socket
Before=sockets.target
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Socket]
ListenStream=22
Accept=no

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target`

This is the contents of /os/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service:
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify
RuntimeDirectory=sshd
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service

Are these files repesentative of an enabled sshd service? Or should I look elsewhere for a solution on why I ssh times out.

If the service is enabled, it should have a symbolic link ssh.service in the directory corresponding to the WantedBy target (i.e. /os/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/) pointing to the service file /os/usr/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service

sshd is not an always-on service any longer, so you won't see it unless an active connection exists. On a stock install of Ubuntu, systemd will listen for connections on the appropriate port(s) listed in the sshd config, and will start sshd when a connection attempt is detected. The newly-started sshd will conduct authentication and handle the new connection. See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sshd-now-uses-socket-based-activation-ubuntu-22-10-and-later/30189

Review journalctl on the server immediately after a timeout. Look for the attempted connection and associated errors. With a timeout, triple-check that the IP address is correct.

@user535733 Thanks for stopping by. I am chrooted and reading journaclt. After the initial reboot, no new entries were are appended to the log. Does this mean the server never started after reboot? My understanding is that journalctl should be heavily populated with various initialization messages on machine startup. Is there any reason why journaclt would stay the same across reboots, other than that the machine didn't start at all??

@user535733  Since my problem seem to be boot related, I've opened another q here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1526659/undu-update-initramfs-or-run-update-initramfs-when-chrooted Thank you for guiding me in the right direction.
