undu update-initramfs or run update-initramfs when chrooted
Remote Ubuntu 24.04 machine does not boot after setting up raid1 on 2 HDDs. I am using rescue system and have removed entries appended by (there were duplicates)
mdadm --detail --scan --verbose | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

and removed the line in /etc/fstab related to my new raid device
/dev/md4   /storage   ext4   defaults   0   0

I have also run update-initramfs -u. I do not know how to undo the effects of this command. I tried running it chrooted, but got an error:
root@rescue / # update-initramfs -u -v
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    are supported and installed on your system.
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
Available versions: 
Nothing to do, exiting.

How do I undo update-initramfs or change it to reflect current entries in /etc/fstab and /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf?
